# HTTP ERROR 500 on the main site but not other links

Tags: .htaccess, http, php-5.6, http-status-code-500

Currently having a problem with a HTTP ERROR 500 being thrown when trying to access the site but when browsing to it works perfectly fine without errors. (Https is required, cant link more than 2 in the post.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being a stray ' inside the SSL configuration.. my bad.